Egg sack identification
Can anyone identify this egg sack? It is on the underside of my organic poblano pepper leaf. No infestations, no bugs around that I can see. In case the picture is not clear, it has a smooth surface, is shiny-ish, and about an inch-inch 1/2 in length. This is in Southern California.

Looks somewhat similar to clutches of some treehoppers.
